# Loadable kernel module trouble with sleep() function call in RedHat

Tags: linux, redhat, kernel-module

I am facing an issue in trying to load an LKM into the RedHat kernel using insmod, but it returns me the following error:-

> Insmod –f tmdq.o
>
> tmdq.o: unresolved symbol sleep

Why should sleep() system call from within the LKM cause an issue? I wish to check if there is some other name given to sleep() in the Red Hat Linux 3.2.2-5, Linux version 2.4.20-8.

Also, is there a way to browse  the source code of RedHat online, without having to download it?

Thanks.

Comment: I think I found the answer. This is where one can browse kernel code: http://lxr.linux.no/. Additionally, symbols of sleep and msleep are not included in the kernel 2.4.20. I will have to implement it on my own using schedule_timeout() function of the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

First, sleep() is not as system call, it is implemented in libc by using sys_nanosleep syscall.

So there is no sleep in kernel, use msleep, mdelay or usleep_range (include/linux/delay.h) or maybe one of wait_event_ functions (include/linux/wait.h)

Answer (score 0):

Definitions of msleep and other variants are not included in the kernel 2.4.20. One will have to implement it on his own using schedule_timeout() function of the kernel.

Additionally, this is where one can browse kernel code: [lxr.linux.no](http://lxr.linux.no/)

Comment: this is exactly how sys_nanosleep syscall is implemented in this ancient kernel, I really feel for you for having to work with such a dated version